# About linear maps - where is the mistake?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I've been thinking about this. My the reasoning seems to imply that:

> If two linear maps $f,g$ disagree somewhere, they must disagree everywhere but $0$.

This feels like it can't be right [edit: it definitely isn't], but I can't see a fault in the reasoning:

> Say $f,g$ linear on $V$ disagree at $x_0$. For any $x\neq 0:$
>
> - If $f(x_0)+f(x-x_0)=g(x_0)+g(x-x_0)$ then $f(x-x_0)\neq g(x-x_0)$.
> - If $f(x_0)+f(x-x_0)\neq g(x_0)+g(x-x_0)$ then $f(x)\neq g(x)$.
>
> So $f\neq g$ on $V\setminus \{0\}$.

I can't find the mistake...

Comment: how do you get the second bullet?

Comment: @Mirko The expressions are exactly $f(x),g(x)$ by linearity. It's $A\implies A$

Comment: then how you get the left-hand side of the second bullet? (that is, how do you get the premise? In essence you are saying: If $f(x)\neq g(x)$ then $f(x)\neq g(x)$, this statement is true, but does not imply $f(x)\neq g(x)$.)

Comment: I am saying *if*. Basically the statements together are either $f(x)\neq g(x)$ or $f(x-x_0)\neq g(x-x_0)$

Comment: On $\Bbb R^2$, the matrices $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ disagree on where to send $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, but not on where to send $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. So there is a counterexample.

Comment: @Arthur Yes thanks, it's clear that it's false now. Just interested in the mistake.

Comment: Statement $A\implies A$ is always true, regardless whether $A$ is true. In essence you are saying: If $f(x)\neq g(x)$ then $f(x)\neq g(x)$, this statement is true, but does not imply $f(x)\neq g(x)$.

Comment: What are the domains and codomains of your maps?!

Comment: @Mirko No I am saying what I said in my second comment... Put differently either $\text{not A}\implies f,g$ disagree at $x-x_0$. Else $A$, where $A$ is $f,g$ disagree at $x$. The posted answer agrees.

Comment: The conclusions in the two bullet points are different: One speaks about $x$ the other about $x-x_0$. Could you make them both say $f(x)\not=g(x)$?

Comment: @Mirko No because then the statement would be true.

Comment: for me the easiest counterexample is rotation about the $x$ axis in three dimensions. I knew the statement was false, just took me a whole to see what exactly you were asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the bullets show is that for any $x$, either $f$ and $g$ disagree on $x$, or they disagree on $x-x_0$. In other words, "If they do agree on $x$, at least they disagree on $x_0-x$". This is quite true, but it's not what the claim says, and therefore it is not a proof.

Comment: Argh right I see it now. My conclusion is rubbish. Thanks.